Updating hash table value in array of hash table in PowerShell
I want to add/update property of object in array.
I have array of objects, where i want to add property 'id' with value from range.
[array] $idRange= @(1, 2, 3)

[hashtable[]] $aoo= @(@{})*$idRange.Count
foreach ($id in $idRange) {
  $i = $idRange.IndexOf($id)
  $aoo[$i].set_Item('id', $id)
}

Expected result is to have
@(@{'id'=1}, @{'id'=2}, @{'id'=3})
but .set_Item writes in all items in array and over iterating values are like
@(@{'id'=1}, @{'id'=1}, @{'id'=1})
@(@{'id'=2}, @{'id'=2}, @{'id'=2})
@(@{'id'=3}, @{'id'=3}, @{'id'=3})

what am I doing wrong?

pwsh --version => PowerShell 7.4.5

It seems that [hashtable[]] $aoo = @(@{})*$idRange.Count doesn't create an array of 3 discrete hashtables - it creates an array that contains 3 references to the same hashtable - try [object]::referenceequals($aoo[0], $aoo[1]) for example - you'll get true output. If you use $aoa = 1..$idRange.Count | foreach-object { @{} } instead it will create an array of 3 individual hashtables...

You are overthinking.
# Create the Id array.  
# Prepending [int[]] forces it to be a Int Array, otherwise it will be a Object
# Array containing Int objects. 
[int[]]$idRange = 1, 2, 3

# Assigning a Foreach to a Variable causes every Success Stream(stdOut) output
# in the loop to be added to the Variable as a array element.  
# This is more efficient than adding each element individually unless you need
# to add\remove elements later: in that case look for Lists.   
# Prepending [hashtable[]] forces it to be a Hastables Array, otherwise it will
# be a Object Array containing Hashtable objects. 
[hashtable[]]$aoo = foreach ($id in $idRange) {
    # this creates a Single Property Hashtable with the property Id with value
    # $id and pushes it to the Success Stream, thus being captured by the $aoo
    # variable as one element of its array.   
    @{id = $id }
}

$aoo

PS ~> .\test.ps1
Name                           Value
----                           -----
id                             1
id                             2
id                             3


[int[]] $idRange = 1..3 for -3 bytes. Oh, wait this isn't codegolf.stackexchange.com :-)

@mclayton yes but.. is it Teh Most Efficient? ;P

@mclayton, yes, i could use random function for this

Tnx! I can do just [hashtable[]]$aoo = foreach ($id in $idRange) { @{} } to get array of empty hashtables and $aoo[2]['x'] = 7 for adding/updating properties, right?

I accept @sirtao's answer.
Meanwhile I was working on .Net in powershell to do this properly
$aoo = New-Object System.Collections.Hashtable[] $idRange.Count
foreach ($i in $idRange) {
    $i = $aoo.IndexOf($uid)
    $aoo[$i] = New-Object System.Collections.Hashtable
}

this way I can add/set/update properties like this for case in my question
foreach ($id in $idRange) {
    $i = $idRange.IndexOf($id)
    $aoo[$i]['id'] = $id
}

or add/set/update just one parameter (for what I need)
$aoo[2]['x'] = 7

